# sscanf starts to read from begining

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
int main(){
    int i,j;
    char *data = "1\n2\n";
    sscanf(data, "%d", &i);
    sscanf(data, "%d", &j);
    printf("i=%d, j=%d\n", i, j);
    return 0;
}
```

If you [run the code](http://codepad.org/6mGWfWO0) you'll see this

```
i=1, j=1
```

Why `j=1` here? Shouldn't it be `2`? Am I missing something very basic?

If I use `sscanf(data, "%d\n%d", &i, &j);` it shows correct output. But now the next sscanf call will start reading from beginning again? **Why is this? how to read it properly?**

Comment: You specify `data` as the starting point, don't you? What else did you expect?

Comment: yes you are missing something very basic, you start from the same address and read an integer *twice* and get the same value twice. no surprises there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two `sscanf` lines can be rewritten as:

```
sscanf("1\n2\n", "%d", &i);
sscanf("1\n2\n", "%d", &j);
```

It should be fairly obvious now why both `i` and `j` have the value `1`. `sscanf` can't modify where `data` points.

Use a single `sscanf` call to extract both tokens instead:

```
sscanf(data, "%d\n%d", &i, &j);
```

Comment: In the main code I have lot of other tokens I want to read. Even their lengths are dynamic. See [this](http://pastie.org/5398470) (line 76)

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: You can extract all those tokens with a single `sscanf` call. If you want to be inefficient you can manually update the pointer to the next delimiter by using `strchr`.